# windbg -remote does not connect to localhost on Server 2012

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

I'm attempting to debug the startup of a service using the IFEO method (which I've successfully done on server versions prior to Windows 2012 on scenarios other than startup). The `Debugger` reg value is `c:\debuggers-x64\cdb.exe -server tcp:port=1234`. I then start the service and verify that cdb.exe is listening using `netstat -na | findstr 1234` (I verified nothing was listening on this port prior to starting the service). Then I attempt to connect to the debugging server like this `windbg.exe -remote tcp:server=localhost,port=1234` but it hangs for maybe 15-30 seconds and then fails. I try again and while it's hanging I run `netstat -na | findstr 1234` again and it shows cdb.exe listening on port 1234 and it also shows a SYN_SENT to 127.0.0.1 on port 1234 (presumably sent by windbg.exe). It remains in the SYN_SENT state until windbg.exe reports a failure to connect.

So TCP connection establishment never completes. I checked the firewall and it's turned off. I also tried using the IP address of the network adapter (as opposed to `localhost`) but I get the same behavior. I also tried having cdb.exe listen on a port > 5000 but that also has the same behavior.

Does anyone know if there's new security introduced in Server 2012 for accessing TCP ports?

thanks

Comment: i usually don't use localhost if implied, and use a port range; my setup looks like this: `-server tcp:port=5000:5100` and `-remote tcp:port=5000:5100`. As a side note, you could try procmon to inspect network traffic and detect possible connection issues.

Comment: Thanks @deemok. Have you been able to do this on server 2012?

Comment: nope, i never had to do on this specific server os, but i will give it a try first thing in the morning.

Comment: unfortunately, we're still a bit behind and the test lab does not have any systems with 2012 server installed. did you have any progress?

Comment: @deemok no progress on the tcp transport but my coworker tried named pipes and that worked. He did this for the server `c:\windbgx64\cdb.exe -server npipe:pipe=PipeName` and this for the client `C:\windbgx64>windbg.exe -remote npipe:server=localhost,pipe=PipeName`.